# Solving a Lindblad differential equation in matrix form

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, quantum-computing

I am trying to solve the following Lindblad equation analytically with Mathematica:

$$\frac{d\rho}{dt}=-i[H,\rho]+\sum\nolimits_{i=0}^1 K_i\rho K_i^+-\frac12\cdot\{K_i^+K_i,\rho\},$$
where
$$H=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},$$

$$K_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},$$

$$K_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

My code looks like this:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
H[t_] = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1}};
K1 = {{1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1/Sqrt[2], 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, -1/Sqrt[2]}};
K1plus = ConjugateTranspose[K1];
K2 = {{1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1/Sqrt[2], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1/Sqrt[2], 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, -1/Sqrt[2]}};
K2plus = ConjugateTranspose[K2];
eqn = I*D[rho[t], t] == -I*H[t] . rho[t] + I*rho[t] . H[t] + 
    K1 . rho[t] . K1plus - 1/2*K1plus . K1 . rho[t] - 
    1/2*rho[t] . K1plus . K1 + K2 . rho[t] . K2plus - 
    1/2*K2plus . K2 . rho[t] - 1/2*rho[t] . K2plus . K2;

sol = DSolve[eqn, rho, t]
```

Nevertheless, I don't get the exact solution. Mathematica only prints the input `DSolve[...]`.

Does that mean that it can't find the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) can't automatically determine the dimensionality of your solution.
Instead it assumes it to be scalar. To solve it as a matrix, you have to provide it as a matrix
$$\rho(t)=\begin{pmatrix}\rho_{1,1}(t) & \rho_{1,2}(t) & \dots\\\rho_{2,1}(t) & \rho_{2,2}(t) & \dots \\\vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{pmatrix}$$

You can do this easily with [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html):

```
rhoMat = Table[rho[i][j][t], {i, 1, Length@K1}, {j, 1, Length@K1}];
```

The replace every occurence of `rho[t]` with `rhoMat`:

```
eqn = I*D[rhoMat, t] == -I*H[t] . rhoMat + I*rhoMat . H[t] + 
    K1 . rhoMat . K1plus - 1/2*K1plus . K1 . rhoMat - 
    1/2*rhoMat . K1plus . K1 + K2 . rhoMat . K2plus - 
    1/2*K2plus . K2 . rhoMat - 1/2*rhoMat . K2plus . K2;
```

Plug this into DSolve and get your solutions:

```
DSolve[eqn // Flatten, rhoMat // Flatten, t];
First[rhoMat /. DSolve[eqn // Flatten, rhoMat // Flatten, t]]
```

> {{C[1], E^((2 + I) t) C[2], E^((2 + I) t) C[3],    E^(2 I t) C[4]},
> {E^((-2 + I) t) C[5], C[6], E^(2 I t) C[7],    E^((-2 + I) t) C[8]},
> {E^((-2 + I) t) C[9], E^(2 I t) C[10], C[11],    E^((-2 + I) t)
> C[12]}, {E^(2 I t) C[13], E^((2 + I) t) C[14],    E^((2 + I) t) C[15],
> C[16]}}

Btw, I think you added an unnecessary `I` infront of the time derivative. The original Lindbladian does not feature this.

---

**EDIT**: When I solve the Lindbladian, I usually do not take [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html). Instead I reduce the problem to
$$\rho'(t)=M\rho(t)$$
Which can easily be done with [`CoefficientArrays`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientArrays.html) and then solved as a [`Eigensystem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem.html) problem. I paste the code for your equation here (ommiting the `I` whih I think is wrong).

```
eqn = -I*H[t] . rhoMat + I*rhoMat . H[t] + K1 . rhoMat . K1plus - 
   1/2*K1plus . K1 . rhoMat - 1/2*rhoMat . K1plus . K1 + 
   K2 . rhoMat . K2plus - 1/2*K2plus . K2 . rhoMat - 
   1/2*rhoMat . K2plus . K2;

systemMatrix = Last[CoefficientArrays[Flatten@eqn, Flatten@rhoMat]];

{eigVec, eigSys} = Eigensystem[mat2];
sol = Total[
   Table[(Exp[eigVec[[i]]*t]*eigSys[[i]]*C[i]), {i, 1, 
     Length@eigVec}]];
sol = rhoMat /. Thread[Flatten[rhoMat] -> sol]
```

> {{C[16], E^((-1 + 2 I) t) C[4], E^((-1 + 2 I) t) C[3],    E^(-2 t)
> C[12]}, {E^((-1 - 2 I) t) C[8], C[15], E^(-2 t) C[11],    E^((-1 - 2
> I) t) C[7]}, {E^((-1 - 2 I) t) C[6], E^(-2 t) C[10], C[   14], E^((-1
>
> - 2 I) t) C[5]}, {E^(-2 t) C[9], E^((-1 + 2 I) t) C[2],    E^((-1 + 2 I) t) C[1], C[13]}}

Besides the enumeration of the constants, the solutions are identical. With this approach, one can also easily solve for initial value problems with
$$\rho(0)=m_{eig}^TC$$

For which $C$ is your sought after vector of constants, $m_{eig}$ the eigensystem matrix and $\rho(0)$ your intial boundary values.